# What do these operators do?

Tags: programming, sketch

Going through the "timeouts" example of the elapsedMillis library (https://github.com/pfeerick/elapsedMillis) I found the following statement:

digitalWrite(LEDPIN, flashPattern[ledIndex++] ? ledBrightness : !ledBrightness);

- flashpattern is an array of boolean variables  (boolean flashPattern[] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0 };)
- ledBrightness is a boolean as well.

What does the "?" and the ":" do there? are these boolean operators?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
A ? B : C;
```

is shorthand for

```
if(A) {
    B;
} else {
    C;
}
```

Comment: It is not. `B` and `C` are not allowed to be statements or blocks, and `if` is not a valid RHS.

Answer (score 5):

They are the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). If the expression before the `?` is true then the result is the expression before the `:`, otherwise it is the expression after.

Comment: Also known as Ternary Operators http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html